# Hex Grid Functions Turns out Empty

Tags: postgis, pgsql2shp

I'm trying to implement this [function](http://rexdouglass.com/spatial-hexagon-binning-in-postgis/) to create a hex grid over a layer.

However, when I implement it and export it via `pgsql2shp` the results ends up empty. The query I used is below

```slq
CREATE TABLE hex_grid (gid serial not null primary key);
SELECT addgeometrycolumn('hex_grid','the_geom', 0, 'POLYGON', 2); 

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION genhexagons(width float, xmin float,ymin  float,xmax float,ymax float  )
RETURNS float AS $total$
declare
    b float :=width/2;
    a float :=b/2; --sin(30)=.5
    c float :=2*a;
    height float := 2*a+c;  --1.1547*width;
    ncol float :=ceil(abs(xmax-xmin)/width);
    nrow float :=ceil(abs(ymax-ymin)/height);

    polygon_string varchar := 'POLYGON((' ||
                                        0 || ' ' || 0     || ' , ' ||
                                        b || ' ' || a     || ' , ' ||
                                        b || ' ' || a+c   || ' , ' ||
                                        0 || ' ' || a+c+a || ' , ' ||
                                     -1*b || ' ' || a+c   || ' , ' ||
                                     -1*b || ' ' || a     || ' , ' ||
                                        0 || ' ' || 0     ||
                                '))';
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO hex_grid (the_geom) SELECT st_translate(the_geom, x_series*(2*a+c)+xmin, y_series*(2*(c+a))+ymin)
    from generate_series(0, ncol::int , 1) as x_series,
    generate_series(0, nrow::int,1 ) as y_series,
    (
       SELECT polygon_string::geometry as the_geom
       UNION
       SELECT ST_Translate(polygon_string::geometry, b , a+c)  as the_geom
    ) as two_hex;
    ALTER TABLE hex_grid
    ALTER COLUMN the_geom TYPE geometry(Polygon, 4326)
    USING ST_SetSRID(the_geom,4326);
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$total$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

--width in the units of the projection, xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax
SELECT genhexagons(1.0, -124.8, 25.10, -66.9, 49.6);
```

And then I export it using the pgsql2shp `pgsql2shp -f test -h wideload -u minhmai -P password! test_nd_2016g "select * from hex_grid"`

But when I open it in QGIS, the shapefile is blank. I'm not sure about what the function **really** does but I assume it should have something when exported, especially since the output indicated that there are rows.

Comment: Have you tried just adding the table to QGIS without exporting to a shapefile?

Comment: @alpha-beta-soup, actualy it does show up. Do you know why it wouldn't when exporting using `pgsql2shp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you need to use the `-g` flag to specify the name of your desired geometry column if you want your geometry to be exported, too. Something like `pgsql2shp -f test -h wideload -u minhmai -P password! -g the_geom test_nd_2016g "select * from hex_grid"`.

---

<sup>The reason I asked if you could just add it to QGIS is to test whether your table actually had records, but also because I really encourage you to *not* create a shapefile. There is nothing you can do with a shapefile that you can't do with a table in PostgreSQL, and there is a lot you can't do with a shapefile that you can do with a PostgreSQL table. You'd really be selling yourself short, unless you have a compelling reason to use a shapefile. Compatibility with legacy software and unfamiliarity with SQL are the only justifiable reasons I can think of, and the latter can only be overcome with deliberate experience. If you just want an exchange format, try a GeoPackage, or even just a SQL dump. The moment you produce a shapefile, and then modify it, you will have an additional step before you can then relate it back to any other PostgreSQL tables, and two conflicting versions of your hex grid.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I didn't want to necessarily export it, I was just curious to visually examine what hex function created.

Comment: Yep, which you can do without exporting: QGIS began life as a PostGIS viewer.